# Passing a generic list to a method

Tags: c#

I have an application that will parse an excel file and add a column, then generate a new CSV file with the results.  I am able to create a list of the items I want in the file, but I cannot figure out how to pass that list to the method that is generating the new file.

I have the following class:

```
public class LocationData
{
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Partner { get; set; }
    public string LocationID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Market { get; set; }
}
```

and the following code to get the data into a list:

```
LocationData Locationdata = new LocationData()
{
    PostalCode = location[0],
    Partner = location[1],
    LocationID = location[2],
    Name = location[3],
    Country = location[4],
    Market = repository.GetMarketsForPostalCode(location[0])
}
```

I also have the method to create the csv and I need to pass in the list info, but I get the error:

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'app.LocationData' because 'app.LocationData' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: Your LocationData is not a list that can be enumerated. You need a list of them. One way is this: `List<LocationData>`.

Comment: I am confused. You dont actually create a list anywhere here. LocationData is just class. Create a list or array of them first. and what method are you trying to use?

Comment: sorry, forgot to post the actual list. haha.  but you did make me realize that somehow i missed the fast that i am not adding items to the list anywhere.  Just brain dead, that's what i get for working so late.  thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding what a list is in C#. I think you need the `List` data type. Try this:

```
List<string> Locationdata = new List<string>()
  {
    location[0],
    location[1],
    location[2],
    location[3],
    location[4],
    repository.GetMarketsForPostalCode(location[0])
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your csv function will look like this

```
        public void GenerateCSV(List<LocationData> data)
    {
        foreach (LocationData d in data)
        {
            //put line in csv as
            string s = d.PostalCode + "," d.Partner + _"," + d.LocationID...... + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
```

Your class declaration will remain same

```
public class LocationData
{
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Partner { get; set; }
    public string LocationID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Market { get; set; }
}
```

Now you need to add all the data in the list first
which you will do like this

```
            List<LocationData> lst = new List<LocationData>();

        LocationData ld = new LocationData();
        ld.LocationID = "0";
        ld.Market = "market";

        lst.Add(ld);
        ........
        GenerateCSV(lst);
```